# "Convex" sequence converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

If I have a sequence $\{ a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ that satisfy the property that (for all $x\in [0,1]$) $x \: a_{n-1} + (1-x)\: a_{n+1}> a_n$ and $a_{n+1}< a_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. It is true that te sequence converge? I see it graphically because is like the sequence would be "convex", but I'm not sure if it is true. Thanks

Comment: Is this for a fixed $x$? Or for every $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence is decreasing but may have no lower bound, hence no limit. For example if $a_n=-\ln n$ for every $n.$

Comment: Thanks! So, if $\{a_n\}$ was a lower bound, it has limit, right? and the "convex" restriction it is not necessary?

Comment: Yes. A decreasing sequence with a lower bound converges to its glb.